# Can a "Code by Zapier" step be reused?

Tags: javascript, datetime, zapier

Backstory: I'm trying to solve Javascript timezone issues when using a `Code By Zapier` step. Other triggers and actions seem to recognize my timezone but the `Code By Zapier` step doesn't run on my machine so it's not too surprising it would use some other timezone. I can solve this by doing a fetch to Googles Timezone API and figuring out the offsets. Well and good but it ends up being a few lines of code. Turns out I'll need this piece of info in multiple Zaps.

Question: Is there any way to write a `Code By Zapier` step once and invoke it via a filter, action or trigger step? Is there some other trick for reusing code? I don't think there is but after playing with `Code by Zapier` for just a short while I'm realizing there's a **LOT** of non-obvious power and functionality that can be exploited so I thought I would ask. Alternately, if there's a simpler way to solve getting a `new Date()` in my local timezone I'd like to know that too.

Comment: The way you've emphasized `Code By Zapier` in code ticks makes this read like a very confusing ad. (just my .02$)

Comment: Those three words are the actual name of the "App" in Zapier. My experience with SO is that using the code ticks is the preferred way to format this, I suppose quotes or italics would also have worked but no sure it would make it seem less like an ad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding reusing code, the easiest way might be creating your own Zapier app which allows you to write full JavaScript in a dedicated file that can be designed how you wish (to reuse code, etc). Then, since that's your own custom "action" you can (re)use that action in any zap.

Comment: Took a couple of hours to work through the docs and figure it all out but thanks for suggesting this. I had no idea it would be so easy, plus now I can easily share with others in the organization.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. It would be nice to have a global zap step that one can reuse across all zaps. It sounds to me like Zapier apps would be public too... Anyway, thank you for the tip @Matt